# loading custom appearance values

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know in which function e.g `viewDidLoad` etc.. would be the best approach to load custom view properties like image border heights, color, all appearance.

For example I add custom values like these in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which I think is not best way to do it:

```
// corner radius
        cell.feedImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        // border
        cell.feedImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        cell.feedImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor


        cell.feedImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

And these `navigationBar` appearance I load in viewDidLoad and i use it in many views:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        let fontDictionary = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white ]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = fontDictionary
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.184, green: 0.996, blue: 0.855, alpha: 1.00)
```

So the question again, where should I load appearance values? I ask it because right now I am in situation where my image border is loading before image etc..

There are so many functions like `viewDidLoadAppearance()`, `ViewDidload()`. I've read many questions where they ask what is difference between them but I still do not know where is best to load appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically 3 different options.

1) You could get or set those values in the `viewDidAppear()` func, after they have been completely instantiated.

2) You could get or set them in the `vieDidLayoutSubviews()` function and set a bool to check if your task has been called.

```
var didConfigureUI = false
func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if !didConfigureUI {
        didConfigureUI = true
        updateUI()
    }
}
```

3) You could get or set them in the viewDidLoad using `layoutIfNeeded()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    xy.view.layoutIfNeeded() // <- This will update your initial view frames
    updateUI()
}
```

And your func to do whatever:

```
func updateUI() {
   //f.e  feedImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

And to do it in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, you would do something like this, using the `layoutIfNeeded()` as well.

```
    cellForRowAtIndexPath {

          let cell = tableView.blahblahcell
          updateUICell(cell.feedImageView)
    }

    func updateUICell(imageView: UIImageView) {

        imageView.layoutIfNeeded()
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
```

And to answer the last question about the lifecircle:

The circle is:

```
    init    
    UIViewController awakeFromNib
    loadView  // your pictureImageView is loaded here
    UIView awakeFromNib
    UIViewController viewDidLoad
    viewWillAppear 
    viewDidAppear // the properties of your pictureImageView are available here
```

Comment: Awesome explenation. Thanks for that clarification :) But what about that if I call f.e the navbar appearance in every viewcontroller? Shuld I make some global func and call it?

Comment: I assume your point is, that if you call the same func in every controller, you would save lines of code, if you would refactor it. Then yes. You should do that. You should then create the Constructor like this `func myGlobalFunc(vc : UIViewController) {}` because - I just woke up and I don't have Xcode open, but with navbar, you're calling `self.navigationController......` and with a global func, you can't call self, but you need to pass `self` as `vc`

Comment: that would be then `vc.navigationController......` and when you call the func `myGlobalFunc(self)`